# how to add a uibarbuttonitem in settings bundle?

Tags: iphone, settings, bundle

I would like to add a uibarbuttonitem in the settings bundle in my app. How to implement this? What's more, I want to implement the function dragging the items of settings bundle in my app to adjust the orders of the items. How to implement it? I find the 'General' of iphone settings bundle has such functions.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible for non-Apple apps on a non-jailbroken device. I would suggest either having the settings in-app, or rethinking your approach.